# how to use only the parent's class, even when overridden

Tags: java, inheritance

how do we set a particular method call within a parent's code to always use the parent's version of that method, regardless of the child class?

```
class Parent {

    public void Method1() {
        // some code
    }

    public void Method2() {
        Method1(); // but I want to draw from PARENT Method1()
    }

}

class Child extends Parent {

    public void Method1() {
        // some other code
    }

}

public Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Parent obj;

        obj = new Child();

        obj.Method2();

        obj.Method1(); // here it should use the Child Method1()

    }

}
```

how can I make this happen?  I have no idea how to even phrase the question to search it (despite a lot of effort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
Parent.this.Method1();
```

UPDATE:

As a matter of fact this won't work.

Here is the test code:

```
public class Parent {
    public void Method2() {
        Parent.this.Method1();
    }

    public void Method1() {
        System.out.println("Parent.Method1()");
    }
}


public class Child extends Parent {
    public void Method1() {
        System.out.println("Child.Method1()");
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Child.Method1()
```

This should be unmarked as the right answer. Please consider one of the other answers here.

Comment: Isn't that notation for inner classes?

Comment: I'm not so sure about that... I get a "No enclosing instance of the type Parent is in scope" error. Can you provide some code that will work?

Comment: I have to say though, the fact that `Parent.this` worked inside `Parent` itself was new to me.

Comment: @BheshGurung the code he provided worked, I knew exactly what I needed, and I stated in the original post that I was not quite sure how to word the question to get a proper answer through a search engine.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to create a private method in your `Parent` class that has the functionality you want in `Method1`, then call that from your `Parent`'s method 1.

```
class Parent {

    public void Method1() {
        Method1Private();
    }

    public void Method2() {
        Method1();
    }

    private void Method1Private() {
        // some code
    }

}
```

This method allows your subclasses to override `Method1` if they need to but inherit the parent's behaviour if they want, while the parent's behaviour can't be modified by a subclass. You should consider making methods `final` instead, because the class design could become confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want subclasses to override a method, use `final`:

```
public final void Method1() {
    // some code
}
```

Wanting to never use a subclass's implementation is the same as not wanting them to implement it.

Comment: OP seems to say that this behavior is only desired for one particular call, I think